# Compare time from DateTime column using JPQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I am trying to Compare time from DateTime column using JPQL. For example **Table1** contain **appointmentDate** is a column type Date and **appointmentTime** is a column type Date.

I got required output with native query, The Query is

```
select * from table1 where appointment_date>curdate()-1 and TIME(appointment_time) between '09:00:00' and '12:00:00';
```

How to convert this query into JPQL or  CriteriaBuilder. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no TIME function in JPQL (as any JPQL reference would tell you). You have to find a function specific to your RDBMS and use JPA 2.1

```
"FUNCTION('sqlTimeFunction', args) BETWEEN :val1 AND :val2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following native query, it's working for me:

```
select * from table1 where hour(appointment_time) >= 9 and hour(appointment_time) <= 12
```

Comment: Please use English in the non-shortcut way on SO. Also highlight your code by leaving a blank row and indenting code by 4 spaces. And welcome to SO.